# QTip2: Why does viewport not work with absolute positioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, qtip2

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/2761/

I understand the concept of why it wouldn't via css, but not sure if the same behavior would apply to this tooltip plugin

```
initializeToolTip: function () {
    $(".offer-item").each(function () {
        $(this).hover().qtip({
            content: {
                text: 'loading...',
                title: {
                    button: true
                },
                ajax: {
                    url: '/Fakepath/ToolTips/ToolTipHover',
                    type: 'GET'
                }
            },

            style: {
                classes: { tooltip: 'auction-item-tooltip' }
            },

            show: {
                solo: true
            },

            position: {                
                viewport: $(window),
                target: $(this),
                my: 'top right',
                at: 'top right',
                adjust: {
                    method: 'flip flip',
                    x: 280,
                    y: -20
                }
            },

            hide: 'unfocus'

        });
    });

},

initializeCloseToolTip: function () {
    $('a.close-tooltip').live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.qtip').qtip('hide');
    });
}
```

Trying to get the last element to flip sides when outside of the window to no avail. Been looking at position.container and viewport to no avail. Anybody know if I'm doing something wrong? I have 5 's with tool tips next to each other, then on the last one I want the positioning to switch to 'top left' and opposite positioning.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks for your time! Awesome plugin btw!

Here's some SS's of whats going on.

Regular: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjWNX.jpg

Cut-off https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPXlq.jpg

Edit: Added jsFiddle, link to dev forum http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-viewport-not-working-with-absolute-positioning?pid=12829#pid12829

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the author, the viewport and absolute positioning options do not work in tandem.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-viewport-not-working-with-absolute-positioning